# Android ViewPager Displaying TextView in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm trying to set up a ViewPager with a number of layouts with 2 TextViews in each layout. I'm having trouble getting my TextViews to display properly when i run my app. My pager works fine but it's not displaying the Textviews i have in my XML layout.

Here's my code that I have in my PageAdapter

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public int getCount() {
    return 31;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    int resId = 0;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.main_menu;

            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.article1;

            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.article2;

            break;
         ....
         ....

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
```

This is what I have for my XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/background"                     android:clickable="true" 
android:id="@+id/layout13" 
android:weightSum="0">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="@string/article13"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="302dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/body13"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@id/viewPager" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried Moving the  around in my XML layout to right underneath my LinearLayout and i get the full screen but all my text disappears. It's probably something simple i'm missing but any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you explain it clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one ViewPager. My app has 9 fragments and one activity. The viewpager is declared once in main.xml. Here's what the important code looks like:

```
public class Polling extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

    //here's the code that makes a tab, adds it to the actionbar, adds a tabadapter, and coordinates the viewpager:

bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.login),
                LoginFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.economics),
                EconFragment.class, null);
```

So that's my main class. You'll lose I never actually directly employ the entire main.xml: the Content View gets set to the ViewPager rather than a layout. Then, inside my main activity, I have an inner class that handles the ViewPager going left/right, as well as the management of my actionBar tabs. But it doesn't sound like you are using tabs, so this next bit of code may not be that helpful:

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return (SherlockFragment)Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            //Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try placing your ViewPager above the textViews, nested directly beneath the LinearLayout. I'm sorry I can't be of more help than that - my experience with ViewPager has been alongside a TabAdapter/actionBar tabs.

Here's the code to my Pager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

All of the rest of my interface comes from other tabs, so this is the entirety of my main.xml. Basically I'm posting this to say that I've got my viewpager as the sole child widget inside a linear layout, and it manages the whole screen.

Comment: I've tried implementing this with no luck unfortunately. When i nest it directly under the LinearLayout both of my text views disappear. When i place the Viewpager underneath the textviews I get the textViews to show but only the bottom section of my layout will scroll, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yea i've got mine set up similar to that with the exception of course of my textViews. I have the Viewpager on each of my XMLs i'm assuming this is how i need to have it? Also i was thinking, do I need to add the textViews under my LayoutInflater within my PagerAdapter? I've been looking for some examples of this as to how this would be done, but have had no luck. thanks again for any input!

Comment: I tried responding in the comment, but it's not long enough. About to post a response for you.

Comment: Awesome! so yea my problem was that i had  the androidViewpager set up in each of my xml layouts.